# crop image php deformed, warped

Tags: php, image, crop

i don't a lot of time to write so will tell you my problem, i have a php code that crops images the good thing is that it crops images really good when i put $thumb_width and $thumb_height with the same value, but in this case i don't what that i want the image with this resolution (200*150) 
here's the code and i cant find the mistake.

```
<?php
function create_thumb($directory, $image, $destination) {
$image_file = $image;
$image = $directory.$image;

if (file_exists($image)) {

$source_size = getimagesize($image);

if ($source_size !== false) {

  $thumb_width = 200;
  $thumb_height = 150;

  switch($source_size['mime']) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
         $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    break;
    case 'image/png':
         $source = imagecreatefrompng($image);
    break;
    case 'image/gif':
         $source = imagecreatefromgif($image);
    break;
  }

  $source_aspect = round(($source_size[0] / $source_size[1]), 1);
  $thumb_aspect = round(($thumb_width / $thumb_height), 1);

  if ($source_aspect < $thumb_aspect) {
    $new_size = array($thumb_width, ($thumb_width / $source_size[0]) * $source_size[1]);
    $source_pos = array(0, ($new_size[1] - $thumb_height) / 2);
  } else if ($source_aspect > $thumb_aspect) {
    $new_size = array(($thumb_width / $source_size[1]) * $source_size[0], $thumb_height);
    $source_pos = array(($new_size[0] - $thumb_width) / 2, 0);
  } else {
    $new_size = array($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
    $source_pos = array(0, 0);
  }

  if ($new_size[0] < 1) $new_size[0] = 1;
  if ($new_size[1] < 1) $new_size[1] = 1;

  $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
  imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, $source_pos[0], $source_pos[1], $new_size[0],                                                                $new_size[1], $source_size[0], $source_size[1]);

  switch($source_size['mime']) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
         imagejpeg($thumb, $destination.$image_file);
    break;
    case 'image/png':
          imagepng($thumb, $destination.$image_file);
    break;
    case 'image/gif':
         imagegif($thumb, $destination.$image_file);
    break;
}


}

}
}
?>
```

in this example, if i put an image of (533px*300px), it's deformed, wrapped "sorry for my english =)", please i need help with this. I would be really plesed if you find the solution.

Thank you, Matias.

Answer (score 1):

This id dilli.

On line 46 you have given more spaces, so you need to remove that unwanted spaces in that line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Usually only one space will be there even if we gave more than one spaces. But here that spaces like multiple of "&nbsp" is present.

Incorrect syntax: imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, $source_pos[0], $source_pos[1], $new_size[0],                               $new_size[1], $source_size[0], $source_size[1]);

Correct Syntax : imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, $source_pos[0], $source_pos[1], $new_size[0],$new_size[1], $source_size[0], $source_size[1]);